# R function andrews() causes "undefined columns error" although proper columns are selected?

Tags: r, package

Reproducible example:

```
install.packages("andrews")
library(andrews)

x = sample(1:200)
y = sample(1:200)
z = sample(1:200)
a = sample(1:200)

dat = data.frame(x = x, y=y, z=z, a=a)

dat$a[dat$a>100] = "old"
dat$a[as.numeric(dat$a)<=100] = "young"


andrews(dat[,1:3], clr = a)
andrews(dat[1:3,], clr = a)
andrews(dat, clr = a)
andrews(dat[,1:3], clr = "a")
andrews(dat[,1:3], clr = 4)
```

Each `andrews()` function causes the same error: `Error in [.data.frame\(df, , clr) : undefined columns selected`. But if I use `head(dat[,1:3])` the correct columns will be shown.

I do not catch it -.-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
install.packages("andrews")
library(andrews)

x = sample(1:200)
y = sample(1:200)
z = sample(1:200)
a = sample(1:200)

dat = data.frame(x = x, y=y, z=z, a=a)

dat$a[dat$a>100] = "old"
dat$a[as.numeric(dat$a)<=100] = "young"

dat$a = as.factor(dat$a)
andrews(dat, clr = 4)
```

Comment: Thank you :) ! I am ashamed, because the solution is this logical -.-